# Python eval function and passing arguments?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, scipy, eval

How can I pass variables to an eval function?

I have tried some solutions posted here on SO as well as reading through the Python documentation

I have this section of code 'v' which I would like to reuse in another part of my code. Here is a snippet:

```py
 v = lambda r5, cdate : somefunc(r4, cdate) + math.exp(-t_3m*r1 - t_6m*r2 - t_1y*r3 - t_2y*r4 - retfrac(d[4], d[5], cdate, eoffset = 730)*r5) + \
                                                      math.exp(-t_3m*r1 - t_6m*r2 - t_1y*r3 - t_2y*r4 - t_3y*r5)
```

I would then like to do something to the likes of:

```py
w = "v(r5, cdate) + math.exp(-t_3m*r1 - t_6m*r2 - t_1y*r3 - t_2y*r4 - t_3y*r5)*(0"
# + some other expressions that I have to build up using a for loop since there is no closed form solution
func = lambda r6, cdate = i[30] : (five_year + (coupon_five_year/2)*(1-(ia_5y/.5))) - (coupon_five_year/2)*(eval(w)) - 100*math.exp(-t_3m*r1 - t_6m*r2 - t_1y*r3 - t_2y*r4 - t_3y*r5 - t_5y*r6)
                r6 = fsolve(func, xguess)[0]
```

When I try to evaluate this, I am getting an error that says:

```py
NameError: name 'v' is not defined
```

Once I remove v, from the expression for w, I then get a NameError for t_3m and it just waters through all of the variables. Could someone please help me out?

Comment: `v` is a function, why can't  you pass arguments to it directly?

Comment: I have tried moving it directly to the function statement, but then I still get a name error on w. I also get an index out of bounds error on 'd' I believe, but I have verified that d has nearly 20 elements.

Answer (score 1):

The eval function accepts two additional parameters to provide it with global and local variables.

You simply need to call it like this: `eval(w,globals(),locals())`

That's assuming the variable references made in the w string are all in scope when you call eval().

Comment: So I did this, and it sorta seems to work. For some reason, it raises an index error for an array that I reference in the string w (the string that gets evaluated. Is it not passing this array properly? I have verified that the array has 20 elements while I call on elements 5 and 6.

Comment: It is sometimes hard to debug issues with eval().  You might try to temporarily replace your eval() call with the actual code contained in the string so that Python can hopefully return a more meaningful error.  You could also try to print `locals()["variableName"]` before the call to see what the function is actually working with.

Comment: Ah, well the list I am using is called d, and there is another list in another program called d which only has 4 elements - hence, causing the problem I believe, The list d in the local scope is correct while the list d in the global scope is bad. Is there anyway I can do, eval(w, None, locals()) and have it work?

Comment: Yes it would work but then your formula may not be able to use some of your global functions,  What you may be able to do is to create a merged local dictionary to pass instead of locals().  e.g. `mergedDict = {**globals(),**locals()}` and then call `eval(w,None,mergedDict)`.  This will let you control the precedence of variable names (although I'm surprised that eval() would use a global 'd' when there is a local 'd' available).

Comment: Finally got that part to work by declaring d as a global to start with. One more quick question: I am getting error that says 
```python
TypeError: <lambda>() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```
I am sending func r6, and cdate = i[30] which is then used in the evaluation of w, where ```v(r5, cdate)``` sits. Do you know the source of this error?

Comment: Most likely the content of locals() or globals() is not what you expect and there is another definition of `v` that is used.

Comment: You may also need to print the content of `w` before execution, just in case the string construction doesn't produce the right formula